# Script to export all Android-relevant resolutions for each layer in an artboard

Tags: javascript, android, adobe-illustrator

### Context

For Android development I am trying to create a script for Illustrator that exports my vector-work from each layer to the `.png`-format, whereby each export has to be provided in all density (`ppi`)-formats Android needs. I know that I can export images like:

```js
png24_settings = function ( ) {
    var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    options.antiAliasing = true;
    options... = ...
    ...
    return options;
}

var file_destination = "Some string with the destination path and name"
var doc = app.activeDocument; //Retrieve active document
doc.exportFile(file_destination, ExportType.PNG24, png24_settings() ); // Exports visible canvas
```

Each layer can be exported by looping over the layers and setting all other layers invisible.
However, I cannot create a loop with the given function that helps me with my density problem.

### Question

The `exportFile()`-func does not take any resolution parameter and, thus, cannot be used to create the different density-files needed for Android (hdpi, xhdpi, ...).
Which option do I have to export each single layer in all the necessary ppi-formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some consultation of the docs I was able to solve my problem.
There exists a function called `imageCapture()` which contains a `resolution`-parameter for the desired ppi ([link to docs](https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/ImageCaptureOptions/#imagecaptureoptions-resolution)). Note that *this function will export all visible layers* on an artboard. Thus, the iteration for the export needs to take care of visibility.

With this information, I can iterate over each layer in my artboard and do the export.
The script would look like the one provided below. I know its a little exhaustive, but I hope it helps to get a clear understanding.

### Provide setup information

```js
// Provide density-information necessary for android
android_densities = [
      120 // ldpi
    , 160 // mdpi
    , 240 // hdpi
    , 320 // xhdpi
    , 480 // xxhdpi
    , 640 // xxxhdpi
]

// Provide settings for image export which takes the respective density as argument
setOptions = function(density) {
    var options = new ImageCaptureOptions();
   
    options.artBoardClipping = true;
    options.resolution       = density // Your desired ppi
    options...                         // Provide other options you'd also like to implement.
    
    return options;
}


// Initialize current document as document to work with
var doc = app.activeDocument; //Gets the active document

// Retrieve current directory of illustrator-document as default path to save to
// If you want to save anywhere else, just provide it here
var filePath = (app.activeDocument.fullName.parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');

// Select current artboard according to current document
// This is the artboard you want to export your layers from
var activeAB = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];
```

**Note:** Android-densities are provided [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp) in the docs.

### Iterative export

```js
// Export, for example, all visible layers.
// Thus, all layers are first iterated, checked for visibility and set invisible.
// Because of the last step all elements have to be cached in an array (= export_layers)
export_layers= []; // Store layers to export
for(var i=0; i<doc.layers.length; i++){
    var layer = doc.layers[i];
    if(layer.visible){
        export_layers.push(i);
        doc.layers[i].visible=false;
    };
}

// Do exports
for(var exportElement=0; exportElement<export_layers.length; exportElement++) {
    
    // Get layer to export
    var layer = doc.layers[export_layers[exportElement]];
    
    // Set this layer visible (it is the only layer visible now, because imageCapture will export all visible layers)
    doc.layers[export_layers[exportElement]].visible=true;
    
    // Iterate over all densities
    for(var densityElement=0; densityElement<android_densities.length; densityElement++) {
        
        // Provide path and name for output image
        var destination_of_file = new File(filePath + "/" + layer.name + "_" + String(android_densities[densityElement]) + ".png");
        
        // Save file with resolution
        doc.imageCapture(destination_of_file, activeAB.artboardRect, setOptions(android_densities[densityElement]));
    }

    // Set visibility to false again for next layer to be exported correctly
    doc.layers[export_layers[exportElement]].visible=false;
}


// Finally, reset the visibility-status prior to the export
for(var resetElement=0; i<export_layers.length; resetElement++) {
    doc.layers[export_layers[resetElement]].visible=true;
}
```

After that you should have all layers in all densities in your specified folder. Of course this can be much more elegant by providing a folder for each resolution and so on - I just tried to keep it to the point for the answer :)